# RESTEasy CORS header over com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer

Tags: java, resteasy, httpserver

I'm working on an application that provides a local rest service. To do this I use `resteasy` (3.5.0) and for server `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`. My goal is to include the `CORS` header in the all replies.
According to the documentation, `resteasy` provides a [`CorsFilter`](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.5.0.Final/userguide/html/ch31.html) filter that puts the header, but nowhere can I find documentation on how I can use it in my case (without using an application server). And at all, how do I make some specific configuration.

I am currently writing this header manually, in each method

```
@Path("/api")
public class Endpoint {

    @GET
    @Path("version")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response version() {
        return Response.ok(new Version())
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to use the filter below are the given url..

https://howtodoinjava.com/servlets/java-cors-filter-example/

Comment: It does not work for me. There, an application server is used and `web.xml` for configuration is used accordingly. For me, a server uses embedded `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`

Comment: you are using any security framework like Spring Security?

Comment: No, I use only resteasy and httpserver http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.5.0.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Embedded_Container.html#d4e1973

Comment: Please follow the like http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.24.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e1486